# Brick Restoration

Tags: paint, brick

I recently bought an older home that has a brick wall by the entrance that was painted the same color as the house (not a fan).

What methods or products do you all recommend using to make this brick wall look like brick again? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

A [similar question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/3706/what-methods-can-i-use-to-remove-exterior-paint-from-brick) already has answers, but I don't find them satisfying. So here's my take:

First, take a look at the surface of the bricks. When people paint over bricks, usually the reason is that the bricks are weathered, stained, have crumbling mortar, and generally look ugly. It's the same as with decks: nobody decides to paint a brand-new deck with that ugly latex orange thing you see around, they only do it as a last resort to try squeeze a season or two out of the deck before replacing it. The bricks you are looking at might have similar problems, and the best thing to do might be to leave them painted.

If the reason they painted them was just bad taste, the best approach is to use a combination of power washer, soap, and a wire brush. Bricks are porous, so depending on how well glued the paint is, the job can range from easy (just power wash) to impossible to do without destroying the bricks. Be particularly careful with a power washer with a jet nozzle, as it can easily go through the bricks and damage them. After a good power wash, you will probably have to repoint them (add mortar to the joints.)

Also check if the wall is built of actual bricks, or if it's just a facade. Depending on the size of the wall and condition of the bricks, replacing the facade might be a better option.